# Подключение к базе данных PostgreSQL с другого ПК (C#)

Tags: c#, postgresql

Возникла проблемка с которой сам не могу разобратся.
Есть приложение на C# WinForms суть его подключении к базе данных(PostgreSQL ) и через texBox добавление данных в таблицу , удаление таблиц и так далее.
Но делема в том что на моем ПК где и стоит PostgreSQl и само приложение работает коректно идет нормально подключение и все супер.
Но как сделать что бы и с другого Пк например я мог конектиться к БД на моем ПК.
Немного мого кода :

```
string connString =
                String.Format(
                    "Server={0};Username={1};Database={2};Port={3};Password={4};SSLMode=Prefer",
                    Host,
                    User,
                    DBname,
                    Port,
                    Password);
```

Строка по которой я подключаюсь.
Что я уже делал :

1. В файле postgresql.conf заменил строку listen_addresses = '*'
2. В файле pg_hba.conf добавлял строку типа
   host     all     all     0.0.0.0/32     password.
   Добавляя разные варианты с ip и password
3. В строку "Host" в коде писал ip которые и были в файле pg_hba.conf.
   Ничего не помогло , подскажите что делать  ? Или я что то упускаю? Читал много что можно как-то напрямую через IP сервера конект делать но я не могу найти этот самий ip сервера.
   Или я не правильно саму строку делаю ? Или я не правильно базу запускаю я хз вобще я запутался и прошу помочь !
   Добавлю ошибки которые были :
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Это не все но такие были с другого ПК

Comment: Примечание: лучше использовать [NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder.html) для конструирования строки запроса вместо string.Format.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18580066/5045688 - здесь смотрели?

Comment: @Alexanderpetrov Спасибо спусть столько времени , оно за работало благодаря Вашему коментарию!